# How can I apply a style rule to multiple categories? (2.14 and above)

Tags: qgis, style, atlas, rule-based, rule

I think this used to be more straightforward in earlier QGIS versions, but with more powerful rule-based styling (great development) I am now a little confused as to how to apply a rule to multiple categories at once in the Style dialogue.

In the example below, I've styled my data using categories. I want to apply the $id = $atlasfeatureid rule to all categories because I'm working on an Atlas.

I'm guessing I'm missing something simple, but can't think what. It's not a problem to apply rule separately to a few categories but when working with 50+ it would be very time consuming.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could add the main rule $id = $atlasfeatureid, without adding symbols:

[image]

[image]

Then select and drag all the other rules over it (over the label part). They should then become dependent of this first rule:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Victor - you mean apply $id = $atlasfeatureid when it's on Single Symbol and then drag all rules over it? If so, I'm not sure what is meant by 'drag the other rules over it' - I'm probably just not thinking straight, sorry!

Comment: No. Create an additional new rule, without giving it any symbol. Then select all the other rules and drop and drag them over this new rule. It will make them dependent of this one.

Comment: Ah, right - I get you now. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the following in the **Python Console** to change all expressions of each rule to `$id = $atlasfeatureid`:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.rendererV2()
for rule in renderer.rootRule().children():
    rule.setFilterExpression('$id = $atlasfeatureid')
```

---

**Edit:**

The above code replaces all expressions entirely. However, if you want to **add another expression to an existing one**, you can use:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.rendererV2()
for rule in renderer.rootRule().children():
    rule.setFilterExpression('({}) AND $id = $atlasfeatureid'.format(rule.filterExpression()))
```

Comment: Aha - great tip! Thanks for this one, I'll try that too.

Comment: @AlasdairRae - Most welcome =)

Comment: @Joseph Great to know. However, shouldn't the script add AND $id = $atlasfeatureid to each of the rules rather than replacing them entirely?

Comment: @Victor - Thanks, edited post to include adding a new expression to the existing ones. Hope this helps!

Comment: @ndawson - Thanks for the edit, that makes sense :)